# Edit text items are being overlapped in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-recyclerview

The problem is each and every time when I send the edittext field from pressing save button I think the items are being overlapped or it may be every time i add the values from edit text field old one may be replaced by new values.They are not appearing in the list.

This is the class from where i send the edit text fields

```
    public class MyEditor extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText textIn,txtHeading;
    Button buttonAdd,btnsave;

    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.editor);
        txtHeading = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heading);
            buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);

        btnsave =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newName = txtHeading.getText().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),BuilderPage.class);
                intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key", nameList);
                nameList.add(newName);
                int listsize = nameList.size();
                for (int i=0;i<listsize;i++){
                    Log.i("Lists are", nameList.get(i)) ;
                }

                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(MyEditor
                        .this,"You added" +newName.toUpperCase()+ "in your view",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my Layout that contains RecyclerView.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView_builderxml"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_builderxml"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="350dp"
            android:id="@+id/edittxtsurvey"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Enter Your SurveyName"/>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom" >


    <SlidingDrawer android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
        android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton"
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_height="120dip">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"

            android:src="@drawable/arrowdown">

        </ImageView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="#1a237e"
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/plaintext"
                android:id="@+id/imgviewplaintext"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:onClick="oOnClick_PlainText"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/checkbox"
                android:id="@+id/imgviewcheckbox"
                android:onClick="OnClick_CheckBox"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgviewradiobutton"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgviewradiobutton"
                android:layout_marginRight="21dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="21dp" />



            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/radio"
                android:id="@+id/imgviewradiobutton"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:onClick="OnClick_RadioButton"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgviewtextbox"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imgviewtextbox"
                android:layout_marginRight="37dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="37dp" />


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/textbox"
                android:id="@+id/imgviewtextbox"
                android:onClick="onClick_textbox"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is my Builder class that contains Builder xml.

```
public class BuilderPage extends ActionBarActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
private RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private RecyclerViewAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.builder_layout);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar1);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<String> nameList = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("key");
    myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_builderxml);

    linearLayoutManager =
            new LinearLayoutManager(this,  

    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);


    myRecyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,nameList);
    myRecyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
    myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    myRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

This my Adapter class

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends    
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder> {

private List<String> itemsName;
private OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> nameList){
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    itemsName = nameList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.text_view,parent, false);
    return new ItemHolder(itemView, this);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != itemsName ? itemsName.size() : 0);

}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
    onItemClickListener = listener;
}

public OnItemClickListener getOnItemClickListener(){
    return onItemClickListener;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    public void onItemClick(ItemHolder item, int position);
}

public static class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    private RecyclerViewAdapter parent;
    TextView textItemName;

    public ItemHolder(View itemView, RecyclerViewAdapter parent) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.parent = parent;
        textItemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.herecomes);
    }

    public void setItemName(CharSequence name){
        textItemName.setText(name);
    }

    public CharSequence getItemName(){
        return textItemName.getText();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final OnItemClickListener listener = parent.getOnItemClickListener();
        if(listener != null){
            listener.onItemClick(this, getPosition());
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Call  `myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);` before you set your adapter.

Comment: sorry to say that this does not solve the issue

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot to illustrate your problem?

Comment: i mean to say that Every time i add the field from editor class and click save button then the value should appear in the Builder class. Here value appears but always new one.suppose i add chrome and save then second time when i add Mozilla chrome disappears and Mozilla  appears in recycler view.

Comment: I want them to be added in the recycler list but it is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same textitemname everytime.change

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int      position) {
holder.setItemName(itemsName.get(position));

}
```

to

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.ItemHolder holder, int      position) {
holder.textItemName.setText(itemsName.get(position));

}
```